# Linking libcutils to native executable

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want my executable to be able to call functions supported by libcuils - like `property_get(...)`.

In the Android.mk I have:
`LOCAL_LDLIBS:=-lcutils`

`ndk-build` returns:
undefined reference to `property_get`

Adding 'default.properties' with `target=android-9` didn't help.

I'm using android-ndk-r8e on ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

`libcutils.so` is not part of official native API, it is not distributed with NDK. You can pull it from any device or even from emulator, and it is reasonable stable across the versions and mods, so I will not discourage you from using it.

On the other hand, the linker would normally say

```
ld: error: cannot find -lcutils
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If it said `undefined reference`, it probably found libcutils.so somewhere on its search path. Maybe, it was a wrong library. Maybe, you set `LOCAL_LDLIBS` for a static library in your Android.mk, and therefore it is ignored.

`LOCAL_LDLIBS` is only relevant for

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

or

```
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: About the last section, I know that and I'm building with include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE).
I'll try your idea (to copy libcutils from my device) 'll let you know about the result. Thanks

Comment: Where did you get libcutils.a before?

Comment: I didn't. First time :)

Comment: So, you got "cannot find -lcutils" along with "undefined reference"?

Comment: No, only "undefined reference..."