# shared memory in android ndk

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I wanted to transfer large data from one process/app to another process/app in **Android**, but some how creating shared memory using Memory File in **Java** layer doesn't work.

So then tried to create shared Memory in android native, somewhere I read
ashmem_create_region API can be used. But looks like this API is not accessible or open. It is inside libcutils.so.

which is at

```
android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/rs/libcutils.so
```

Q1. How to access this library in android native code.

Q2. If it is not possible to access then what is purpose of giving this in ndk tool.

Q3. If somehow I linked libcutils.so and able to create shared Memory in native using libcutils.so Then can I use this fd to map with MemoryFile in Java layer so it will avoid application native copy to write for each data transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**libcutils.so** is shipped in ndk to enable [renderscript integration](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-renderscript-ndk). It remains an undocumented system library, in the sense that Android does not promise to support all its APIs on all platforms, and especially on future platforms, see more on [on android-ndk user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-ndk/QfuNwJ-vZnE).

This said, I should acknowledge that using ashmem is quite safe, as it is explicitly [documented in Java API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html) since v.1. I wrote a short solution for linking against libcutils.so [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596613/192373).

Here is a discussion about `ashmem_create_region()` API and caveats with IPC through this: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-platform/L6a6Xvn4HSI. **tl;nr**: you still need Binder for handshake.

Your Java code can access `fd` using some [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864778/shared-memory-region-in-ndk).

**Update:** new NDK [r9d](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2) is out, and **libcutils.so** is no longer in the `platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib` directory, as [@Tim Murray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988713/tim-murray) promised in comments below.

Comment: After looking into your comments for other question about linking lib I have tried below, also I have copied libcutils.so into my libs/armeabi folder from  android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/rs/libcutils.so                                                                                                                 LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/libcutils.so
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lcutils                                                  Still it gives error : cannot find -lcutils

Comment: Do not depend on libcutils.so in the RS NDK package; it was included erroneously and will be removed in the very near future. (all of the .SOs in there are being removed, only the static libs will remain)

Comment: @Sachin: if you have copy/past from `Android.mk` correctly, you copied libcutils to `/libs/armeabi` and told the linker to look for it in `/libs`; no wonder that it's not found. But in light of [Tim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1988713/tim-murray)'s remark, I would recommend to pull the library from your device or emulator. You can alternatively copy [ashmem-dev.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libcutils/ashmem-dev.c) from the official git repository, and link it (or necessary parts of it) statically it into your library.

Comment: Thanks all, Some how I am able to link this lib in my project, Now I have valid fd for shared memory. Same I have passed in my application. I am sharing this fd by calling PercelFileDescriptor by   pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.adoptFd(fd);   And sending this pfd to other app/process which is remote. In this remote process I am getting  PercelFileDescriptor through which       FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fd);
  FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
  int len = fc.write(bytebuf);
Some how write len = 0,any suggestion why write is failing

Comment: @TimMurray: note that (as of ) `build/core/build-binary.mk` still lists **cutils** and some other leftovers from the `lib/rs` as legitimate system libraries.