# Android NDK: Module MediaEncoder depends on undefined modules: cutils gnustl dl

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I covert a ADT project to Android Studio. however, i kept getting the error when building this project:

Error:(687) Android NDK: Module MediaEncoder depends on undefined modules: cutils gnustl dl

This is what is in the Android.mk. I am new to NTK, anybody can advise the issue here?

```
 # building application library 
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libMediaEncoder
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc .cpp
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -O2 -Werror -Wall 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=  $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main_jni.cpp \
                   h264encoder.cpp \
                   g72x/g726_32.c \
                   g72x/g711.c \
                   g72x/g72x.c 

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcutils\
                          libgnustl\
                          libdl
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you use a project that was configured to be built in the context of AOSP build, not by NDK. But it could still work with a very old version of NDK.

The current version, **r14** which is integrated into Android Studio 2.3, requires some changes to **Android.mk**.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libMediaEncoder
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -O2 -Werror -Wall 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=  $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main_jni.cpp \
                   h264encoder.cpp \
                   g72x/g726_32.c \
                   g72x/g711.c \
                   g72x/g72x.c 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz -ldl
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcutils_prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libcutils_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := {full-path-to}/libcutils.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

To resolve the dependency on **gnustl**, run `ndk-build APP_STL=gnustl_static`, or define **APP_STL** in your **Application.mk** file.

---

Note that your project uses non-public system library **libcutils.so**. This library was once included in NDK (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22017733/192373), but for the last 3 years Google has been struggling to discourage linking to it.

You can build **libcutils.so** yourself as part of AOSP, or you can `adb pull` it from your device or even from a compatible emulator. You can also find this binary somewhere on the Web (e.g. [GitHub](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+libcutils.so)).

The final blow comes with the announced changes to system linking for [Android 7.0 Nougat](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk). TL;NR: any app that depends on this library will not work on future Android versions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install an older version of ndk Android NDK, Revision 10e (May 2015) worked for me and then use that ndk-build