# Cannot build local shared library in Android Ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-make

I want to build library .so for version 4.0.3 but I am unable to do so.
What I feel is that these problems are caused because my .mk file is not
linking with the libraries.

**Android.mk file**

```
Binder.cpp \
BpBinder.cpp \
CursorWindow.cpp \
IInterface.cpp \
IMemory.cpp \
IPCThreadState.cpp \
IPermissionController.cpp \
IServiceManager.cpp \
MemoryDealer.cpp \
MemoryBase.cpp \
MemoryHeapBase.cpp \
MemoryHeapPmem.cpp \
Parcel.cpp \
PermissionCache.cpp \
ProcessState.cpp \
Static.cpp

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lpthread
LOCAL_MODULE := libbinder1
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libcutils libutils
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(sources)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_PTHREADS 
#LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lpthread
#LOCAL_MODULE := libbinder
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(sources)
#include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

This file builds static i.e .a file for me but shows following errors while building shared library.

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: binder1 <= IPCThreadState.cpp
jni/IPCThreadState.cpp:292:8: error: 'pthread_mutex_t' does not name a type
jni/IPCThreadState.cpp:294:8: error: 'pthread_key_t' does not name a type
jni/IPCThreadState.cpp: In static member function 'static android::IPCThreadState*        android::IPCThreadState::self()':
```

I fixed above errors using 
        LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_PTHREADS

But now, at the time of generating library I am getting a huge list of errors.

```
   D:/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-     4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-   androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lpthread
D:/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/binder1/Binder.o: in function android::Vector<android::String16>::do_copy(void*, void const*, unsigned int) const:jni/utils/TypeHelpers.h:142: error: undefined reference to 'android::String16::String16(android::String16 const&)'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you building this project in system tree, or with `ndk-build`?

Comment: ndk-build...i dont know whats system tree! i am new to NDK

Comment: What is this library supposed to do?  Where did you obtain the codebase from?

Comment: i downloaded zip from code.google.com for android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android NDK supports `pthread`s, but does not provide **libpthread** as usual in Linux toolchains. Your first error message will be gone if you use

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_PTHREADS
```

and not add <s>`LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lpthread`</s>

Regarding the undefined reference to `do_copy()`, it comes from system library `libutils.so`. It is not safe to use libraries that are not officially published with NDK (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596613/192373)), so you better rewrite this piece of code.

Probably you received your `Android.mk` file from the *[google source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/libs/binder/Android.mk)* or one of its forks. I doubt that the resulting library will be useable, because the original `libbinder.so` <s>requires system app with elevated permissions</s> will be loaded when your app starts.

Anyways, referring to system libraries as `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` does not work with `ndk-build`. Instead of <s>`LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libcutils libutils`</s> you are expected to write

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lcutils -lutils
```

Comment: What you seem to be suggesting is that the poster is trying to use platform/AOSP-internal functionality not exported to the NDK.  However, the way you are saying it isn't quite accurate and seems to confuse the issues of *exports* vs *permissions*, for example, if you examine the process of a 3rd-party app you will find that libbinder.so is a dependency (one already loaded by zygote) - that does not actually "require a system app with elevated permissions" though it is not intended for 3rd party code to directly interact with, and will be tricky to make any useful use of.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you for clarification. I confirm that `libbinder.so` may be loaded in user process.