# Error: no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'toString'? Gradle+Cmake

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, clang, android-sdk-2.3

`<string>` is included. What is wrong in `std::to_sting(intVar)`?

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). Does it mean CLang does not meet STandarD?

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774009/android-ndk-stdto-string-support) helped, but the answers are not good *(for me)* because:

1. write own std::to_string() is bad idea. Standard is standard. If i write own implementation. I need to wrap it with defines to prevent errors from another compilers/toolchains which does not leak std features. And this impl still leaks full-featured STD.
2. `Application.mk` - is bad idea too since lastest studio offers Gradle+CMake. Makefile is too ugly and hard for manual using.
3. My [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603486/3743145) is better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ndk std::to\_string support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774009/android-ndk-stdto-string-support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean CLang does not meet STandarD?

No, it is because minimal std library set in Android NDK by default.

I use gradle build system:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    // This block is different from the one you use to link Gradle
    // to your CMake build script.
    externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
        ...
        // Use the following syntax when passing arguments to variables:
        // arguments "-DVAR_NAME=VALUE"
        // ------------------- ANSWER -------------------
        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
      }
    }
  }
  buildTypes {...}

  // Use this block to link Gradle to your CMake build script.
  externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {...}
  }
}
```

Read these:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html#variables
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.htm