# Android Qt Application. Application.mk

Tags: android, qt, c++11, qt-creator, qmake

Hello I have got trouble finding out how to use an application.mk file while using qt, qmake and the qt creator for developing my android application.

My problem is the uncompleted c++11 support (look here [Android ndk std::to_string support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774009/android-ndk-stdto-string-support)) which can aperiantly be resolved by seting APP_STL:=c++_static in the application.mk file.

Is there a way to do so with qmake?

Comment: I am also developing an Android App with Qt. But I can not locate Application.mk file ? Where is it ?