# Compiling ndk project with WebRTC

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk, webrtc

I am trying to integrate `WebRTC`'s c++ api to my project. And I was able to build `libwebrtc` and link it on Windows.

This project is cross-platform targeted so it should be compiled with NDK. But when I included `WebRTC` headers, it complains as below:

```
webrtc/p2p/base/icetransportinternal.h(141,42) :  error: no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'
webrtc/p2p/base/icetransportinternal.h(141,42) :  error: no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'
webrtc/p2p/base/transportchannel.h(66,42) :  error: no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'
webrtc/p2p/base/transportchannel.h(66,42) :  error: no member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'
```

I know `std::to_string` is unusable in NDK environment
(see [Android ndk std::to_string support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774009/android-ndk-stdto-string-support)). But wierd thing is that I have successfully built `libwebrtc` for Android.

How do I resolve this situation?

Comment: Did you build the [webrtc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/BUILD.gn#225) target for Android on a Windows machine? I haven't tried but AFAIK cross-compiling for Android is only supported on the Linux platform. Can you provide the command line you used to run GN and to compile?

Comment: @hkjellander Yes, I build the library on Ubuntu 16.04(docker environment) and copied it to Windows machine. It is compile-time error, not linking things.

Comment: @hkjellander For your information the `gn` command I used is below:  

`gn gen out/ReleaseAndroid --args='is_debug=false rtc_include_tests=false rtc_enable_protobuf=false rtc_build_ssl=false rtc_ssl_root="/usr/local/ssl/android-19/include" target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'`

Comment: I'm fixing this here: https://codereview.webrtc.org/2697313003/

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know std::to_string is unusable in NDK environment (see Android ndk std::to_string support).

Depends on which STL you selected; it is available with libc++, but not gnustl (https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/82). Presumable webrtc was built with libc++ and you're using gnustl.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ThePacific/webrtc-android-jni/tree/master/so "download all these files and put in your libs folder then directly use system.load("lib name ");

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is only AEC module support in your link. I would like to grab most feature of WebRTC as possible.