# android NDK complains std::nearbyint is not a member of std

Tags: c++, c++11, android-ndk, qmake

I want use [std::nearbyint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nearbyint) in *android gcc* but then ndk complains that `std::nearbyint` is not a member of std. I have the `cmath` header included in my code & the same builds well for OSX.

**Is there a workaround for this ?** Is possible to write my own version of `std::nearbyint` ?
I am using `NDK14b` on android

Comment: what about just using the `round` function as a workaround?

Comment: Are you sure you're giving the c++11 argument to your gcc?

Comment: solution to your problem is already in stackoverflow- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774009/android-ndk-stdto-string-support

Comment: std::round has the same problem as nearbyint

Comment: I am using Qt & building with .pro files & qmake. need to figure how to add the compiler flags mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774009/android-ndk-stdto-string-support to my .pro files for Qmake.

Comment: @McLOVIN: add `CONFIG += c++11` in your .pro file, you can also use [qRound](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qtglobal.html#qRound) then, that should work with all Qt versions even without c++11 support.

Comment: @McLOVIN yeah but that is a pretty old source you found there, see my comment for modern way and better readable I guess :)

Comment: is there some way I an implement my own version of `nearbyint` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/82. GNU's libstdc++ is overly broad with their feature guards. We're working on stabilizing the NDK's solution for libc++ so we can just move entirely over to that instead.

Comment: thanks for the update. it doesn't work for me no matter whatever CXX flags I put. I am using qmake. it might have to do with that. but this is only a problem with android:gcc it seems

Comment: No cflags/cppflags will affect this. Those feature guards take affect when we build the NDK itself.

Comment: Just tested with latest r17 canary build (as suggested in @dan-albert issue #82), but still got this error. See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14771

Comment: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/82#issuecomment-236979264 (switch to libc++)