# Android cmake cannot find -lpthread

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

I'm trying to compile a shared library using cmake. I followed the instruction on [this tutorial](http://android-cmake.googlecode.com/hg/documentation.html) to change the toolchain for android NDK. 
However, I'm getting the following output error:

```
/home/usr/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lpthread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../libs/armeabi-v7a/libutils.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/utils.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

A bit of googling around and I stumble upon [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164564/cannot-build-local-shared-library-in-android-ndk) post. So I modified my CMakeLists.txt to add:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS"-DHAVE_PTHREADS")
```

but it seems like it still doesn't work. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution??